# How open a aspx page to client's browser from web service hosted in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I have hosted a WCF service in a server & now I want to popup a window for user input after some web service operation. My objective is to open a popup window for that particular user session who triggered the web service operation.

Do I have to do something in IIS or can be done by writing some code in wcf project.

It will be great help if anyone can give some correct direction to start.

Updated:
User is accessing web page A which is located in some Server A from his client system, now user clicks on a button for some operation.
Now operation starts & calls a web service which is hosted in server B.

Now as per some operational condition it should open a web page B on user’s system. Means server should send a request to client system to open a URL on that client’s browser.

Client access -> Page A (Hosted in server A) in a browser -> Clicks a button -> Calls Web Service (Hosted in server B) -> on operational conditions -> will open a Page B on Client browser.
I know we can send response to page A to open page B but is there way to ask the server based web service to open the Page B in that Client's browser?

Comment: Please explain , what you want to acheive.

Comment: Server can not open any webpage on its own in client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can achieve what you want under the current flow.

The component who should display the page is not the WCF service, but it’s the calling client.

The pseudo should be something like:

```
    var serviceClient = new ServiceClient();

    if (serviceClient.SomeBooleanMethod())
    {
        DisplayPopup();
    }
```